# Material-ui v4 Cannot read property 'root' of undefined for every component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've migrated from `Material-UI` v3 to v4.now this error shows up for every component I import:

> app.js:3581 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'root' of undefined
>
> at Button (app.js:3581)
>   at renderWithHooks (app.js:126202)
>   at updateForwardRef (app.js:127721)
>   at beginWork (app.js:128925)
>   at performUnitOfWork (app.js:132576)
>   at workLoop (app.js:132616)
>
> app.js:130381 The above error occurred in the  component:
>   in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button)) (created by Rtl)
>   in StylesProvider (created by Rtl)
>   in Rtl (created by App)
>   in Provider (created by App)
>   in App

React and react-dom are updated as [guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#list) said:

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
```

I've removed `/node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and tried `yarn` but error shows up for every component.

Also found this [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15898) but not any solution...

Comment: You should keep the version for "@material-ui/styles" in sync with the version for "@material-ui/core".

Comment: @RyanCogswell I migrate as the guide said and updated styles too

Comment: The guide was written for the 4.0.0 release of @material-ui/core and just hasn't been updated to reflect the further releases. If you are using "^4.1.0" for @material-ui/core, you should also use "^4.1.0" (rather than "^4.0.0") for @material-ui/styles.

Comment: @RyanCogswell sorry I migrated back to V3 and now I'm back to fix this. I've updated package.json in question
there was a discussion about this problem here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15898 I hope it helps

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, please change the @material-ui/core version to `"@material-ui/core": "4.1.3"` and remove @material-ui/styles from package.json (core is dependent on it, so it should still be pulled in even without being in package.json explicitly). If this still results in the same error, please show the rest of your package.json, In particular, I would be curious whether you have any packages that leverage Material-UI.

Comment: @RyanCogswell comment in Github solved the problem  , I answered comment here you can check and edit the answer if needed.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this [comment](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15898#issuecomment-507476163) in GitHub solved the problem.

```
 "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.0",
```

should be added to package.json

and as said [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15898#issuecomment-507487546)

```
npm ls hoist-non-react-statics
```

will result

```
├─┬ @material-ui/core@3.9.3
│ └── hoist-non-react-statics@3.3.0 
├─┬ material-ui@0.20.2
│ └─┬ recompose@0.26.0
│   └── hoist-non-react-statics@2.5.5  deduped
├─┬ react-hot-loader@4.12.0
│ └── hoist-non-react-statics@3.3.0 
├─┬ react-jss@8.6.1
│ └── hoist-non-react-statics@2.5.5 
├─┬ react-redux@7.1.0
│ └── hoist-non-react-statics@3.3.0 
├─┬ react-router@3.2.3
│ └── hoist-non-react-statics@2.5.5  deduped
└─┬ recompose@0.30.0
  └── hoist-non-react-statics@2.5.5  deduped
```

which is probably causing this issue.