# How to npm packages in Fulcro?

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs, fulcro

I'm following the [Fulcro 3 Dev Guide](http://book.fulcrologic.com/fulcro3/#_using_javascript_react_components), section Using Javascript React Components, with the [Fulcro Template](https://github.com/fulcrologic/fulcro-template) project, trying to import the [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com) React components.

I added the package with `npm install --save @material-ui/core` and modified the `demo_ws.cljs` file

```clj
(ns app.demo-ws
  (:require [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.components :as fp]
            [nubank.workspaces.core :as ws]
            [nubank.workspaces.card-types.fulcro3 :as ct.fulcro]
            [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.mutations :as fm]
            [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.dom :as dom]
            ["@material-ui/core/Button" :default material-button]
            [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.algorithms.react-interop :as interop]
            ))

(def ui-button (interop/react-factory material-button))

(fp/defsc FulcroDemo
  [this {:keys [counter]}]
  {:initial-state (fn [_] {:counter 0})
   :ident         (fn [] [::id "singleton"])
   :query         [:counter]}
  (dom/div
    (str "Fulcro counter demo [" counter "] ")
    (ui-button
      {:variant "contained"
       :color "primary"}
      "Another Button")
    (dom/button {:onClick #(fm/set-value! this :counter (inc counter))} "+")))

(ws/defcard fulcro-demo-card
  (ct.fulcro/fulcro-card
    {::ct.fulcro/root       FulcroDemo
     ::ct.fulcro/wrap-root? true}))
```

and having the error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
    at eval (Button.js:323)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16242)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:18125)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20187)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:337)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:386)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:441)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25739)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24666)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24639)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it wasn't a fulcro issue as mentioned [in](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16202) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574417/material-ui-v4-cannot-read-property-root-of-undefined-for-every-component) [places](https://spectrum.chat/material-ui/general/cannot-read-property-root-of-undefined~3d925876-6eff-4e33-9c9b-a50517328fe4).

What worked for me, as was adding the `hoist-non-react-statics` version `3.3.0` as pointed [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15898#issuecomment-507476163) and updating `react` and `react-dom` packages.